# The preloader does not stop in some browsers. How can this problem be solved?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When creating a layout I don't stop preloader, I don't know what could be wrong. It does not close only in Mozilla Firefox(last version) and Google Chrome(mobile). On the Desktop version of Google Chrome everything works like clockwork

Exactly the same code works perfectly in other projects.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { /* Preloader */
  $('.preloader').delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).attr('style', 'display: none !important');
    $('body').css("overflow", "auto");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10002;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}

.cssload-container {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cssload-circle-1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: rgb(97, 46, 141);
}

.cssload-circle-2 {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: rgb(194, 34, 134);
}

.cssload-circle-3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgb(234, 34, 94);
}

.cssload-circle-4 {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background: rgb(237, 91, 53);
}

.cssload-circle-5 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: rgb(245, 181, 46);
}

.cssload-circle-6 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: rgb(129, 197, 64);
}

.cssload-circle-7 {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background: rgb(0, 163, 150);
}

.cssload-circle-8 {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: rgb(22, 116, 188);
}

.cssload-circle-1,
.cssload-circle-2,
.cssload-circle-3,
.cssload-circle-4,
.cssload-circle-5,
.cssload-circle-6,
.cssload-circle-7,
.cssload-circle-8 {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation-name: cssload-spin;
  -o-animation-name: cssload-spin;
  -ms-animation-name: cssload-spin;
  -webkit-animation-name: cssload-spin;
  -moz-animation-name: cssload-spin;
  animation-duration: 4600ms;
  -o-animation-duration: 4600ms;
  -ms-animation-duration: 4600ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4600ms;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4600ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes cssload-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="cssload-container">
    <div class="cssload-circle-1">
      <div class="cssload-circle-2">
        <div class="cssload-circle-3">
          <div class="cssload-circle-4">
            <div class="cssload-circle-5">
              <div class="cssload-circle-6">
                <div class="cssload-circle-7">
                  <div class="cssload-circle-8">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: UPD:
It works very unstable. It is sometimes (but rarely) loaded , but most often not.

Comment: Just an observation but most often when I see `!important` in CSS it means something is wrong/overly complicated in the CSS and/or classes being used.

Comment: if you change  `$(this).attr('style', 'display: none !important');` to ` `$(this).hide();` does that have a positive effect?

Comment: I changed $(this).attr('style', 'display: none !important'); to $(this).hide(); This did not yield positive effect

Comment: And after I downloaded the project on github, created a repository and opened through github pages, the problem was fixed in Mozilla Firefox, but remained on the mobile phone in Google Chrome

Comment: `$('body').css("overflow", "auto");` is probably causing a re-flow, can you just put that in the CSS to start with? Also try `window.onload = (event) => {
  //inner stuff
};`

Answer (score 0):

I would try removing the delay(500) and the other redundant code you have. For example, setting the attribute of style to display:none will do nothing if the fadeOut has already run since it will be hidden.

you can use a setTimeout() to delay something if that is what you really want.

```
setTimeout(function(){
      $('.preloader').fadeOut();
},500);
```

Example here : https://jsfiddle.net/qok75ufv/

Comment: I tried Your code. The situation is as follows, there is a preloader, after half a second it goes away, the content is shown for half a second and again there is an infinite preloader

Comment: I went to the example jsfiddle page on my Mobile Chrome browser and it worked as expected. Are you sure there is no other code interfering? perhaps you could show an example of a jsfiddle that breaks.